# Give a counterexample or prove this statement

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

We all know that in Real Analysis, if $E$ is Lebesgue measurable, then there is a $F_{\sigma}$ set $F$ such that:
$$F\subset E,\ m(E\backslash F)=0$$

But I want to know whether the next statement hold:

Suppose $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set, is there a $F_{\sigma}$ set $F$ such that:
$$E\subset F,\ m(F\backslash E)=0 $$

Personally, I don't think this statement is correct. But I found it hard to give a counterexample, can anyone help me?

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake, you are right.

Comment: I like this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a counterexample, let $E$ be a dense $G_\delta$ set of measure zero. Assume for a contradiction that $F$ is an $F_\sigma$ set of measure zero such that $E\subseteq F$. Then $G=\mathbb R\setminus F$ is a dense $G_\delta$ set. But then $E$ and $G$ are two disjoint dense $G_\delta$ sets, contradicting the Baire category theorem.

Comment: I understand that $G$ is dense, cause $F$ is a set of measure 0. But I am a little confused about why two disjoint dense $G_{\delta}$ sets contradict the Baire category theorem. Could you please show the detail of this? Or just a hint?

Comment: @foxell A $G_\delta$ set is the intersection of $\aleph_0$ open sets. A dense $G_\delta$ set is the intersection of $\aleph_0$ dense open sets. The intersection of $2$ dense $G_\delta$ sets is the intersection of $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ dense open sets. The Baire category theorem says that the intersection of $\aleph_0$ dense open sets is dense, and therefore nonempty. (More generally, the intersection of countably many dense $G_\delta$ sets is a dense $G_\delta$ set.)

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to your question is NO.  For a measurable set $E$ what we can to is this:
$$
A \subseteq E \subseteq B,\qquad m(E\setminus A)=0,\qquad m(B\setminus E)=0
$$
where $A$ is an $F_\sigma$ set and $B$ is a $G_\delta$ set.

Comment: I know this conclusion, but is there any counterexamples? Or even a proof for the existence of this kind of counterexample is fine.